# Create unique list of names from several sheets

Tags: arrays, excel, list, unique, formulas

I need to extract one unique list of names based on one criteria. So far, so good. However, I also need the formula to look in the correct sheet when extracting this list. Here is my formula so far:

```
IFERROR(INDEX(Indirect(B$2&"!$B$2:$B$30");MATCH(0;IF(ISBLANK(Indirect(B$2&"!$B$2:$B$30");COUNTIF(E$4:$E4;Indirect(B$2&"!$B$2:$B$30"));"")
```

My `Indirect(B$2` refers to my drop down list of my departments. Hence, each department name corresponds with one sheet name. All data available that I want to extract is thus in the range `$B$2:$B$30` in the desired sheet. I am not able to see why this formula fails. Apparently, I have too many arguments, but I struggle to find out where?

---

**Edit:**

Found the problem after taking a walk...! Turned out I had too few arguments. Here is the working formula:

```
IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT(B$2&"!$A$3:$A$30");MATCH(0;IF(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(B$2&"!$A$3:$A$30"));"";COUNTIF(E$4:$E4;INDIRECT(B$2&"!$A$3:$A$30")));0));"")
```

The observant reader may notice that I changed my array from B2:B30 to A2:A30, where my list of names actually where placed.

Comment: I added the Excel tag.

Comment: add a [reproductible example]http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and use stack overflow formatting please.

Comment: Please move your edit to an answer. It's perfectly fine to answer your own questions.